# CSS - how to force text input fill remaining space of container

Tags: javascript, css

I have div and inside that div are floated child divs and one text input. I need force that text input to fill remaning horizontal space and stay on same line unless some min-width condition places that input to next line. Is it possible? I don't wanna use javascript for that.

here is example (write tag and hit enter)

EDIT EXAMPLE: I have div with 300px width. It contains 3 left floated divs with various width  (for instance 30, 60, 100) and one text input. I want to have that text input on same vertical position like that floated divs, so it must automatically shrink to fit remaining space (300-(30+60+100) = 110px). That text input has some min-width, so it prevents it from getting to small and in that case it jumps to next line).

http://plnkr.co/edit/sulxnvR58LnQqyI7ddFK?p=preview

Comment: Question is unclear to me. `width: 94%`?

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding something like this:

```
style="width: 100%; min-width=2000px;"
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/uuL91pnUBkBRHMziaGBs?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use percentage width for the input and overflow hidden?

Add this CSS

```
div.tag-wrapper input[type=text] {
    width: 100%;
}
div.tag-wrapper {
    padding: 5%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```